# How can I make my closed question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have a question about my Open Source Stack Exchange post: [License for almost-open-source code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/license-for-almost-open-source-code)

This question of mine was closed, with the reason, "... does not appear to relate to open source ...".

Today is my first time here and I am not yet used to the intricacies, but what I don't understand is: **I never claimed that my code would be open-source** (it's not, according to definition). I was fully aware of that before I posted the question. But, it isn't completely unrelated either; it is indeed something very close. And, that is why I posted it here.

If the question doesn't fit here, it could have been migrated to a different site. I even asked for re-word suggestions (I edited it myself the best I could to take out the objected to points), but nobody seemed to have any improvement pointers; only "It doesn't belong here".

---

Please suggest how I could improve my question to make it on-topic. I would request that this question be opened so that I could get answers.

---

I do have to say here that within minutes after my post, it was downvoted and bombarded with comments as if I had mischievously posted something inappropriate, when that 'New contributor' tag says, "Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering."! I would have gladly responded to clarifications or modification requests if I had had the chance.

Please, I am not trying to bad-mouth anyone; the Moderators do know better than I and I respect that. But, I would appreciate coming to a friendly and welcoming environment, and not where I would have to tip-toe around.

Comment: If you want to discuss this further, I know you can't comment at the moment, but you can use [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108747/discussion-between-a-das-and-philip-kendall) to do so.

Comment: **Consider asking guidance from your lawyer.** Of course, you'll need to pay him/her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **I never claimed that my code would be open-source**...

That's the crux of it. This site doesn't deal in anything that's not free/open-source, and we can't do recommendations for non-free/non-open licenses (or custom licenses). That's why your question was closed; ultimately, unless you want to change it completely to ask for an open-source license instead, it will remain closed because it's fundamentally off-topic here.

---

Stack Exchange sites all have a help center: [here's ours](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help). It's helpful to read some of the stuff in there before you post on a new site, because each site is different and has different nuances in what's on-topic there. Every help center has an article called ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (always at `/help/on-topic`), which tells you exactly what's okay to ask or not on any given site.

I don't know of any other Stack Exchange sites that your question would be on-topic for, off the top of my head, so I can't migrate your question elsewhere. If you come across a site you think it might be a good fit for, make sure to check that /help/on-topic article I mentioned to make sure before you post it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And, thank you for the way you said it. :-)

Comment: After some more research, I have modified my [question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/license-for-open-source-code-with-additional-clauses). Please review it.

Comment: @a_das with respect, you have changed your question to read "*I want a licence that is just like an open-source licence except you can't modify or re-use my code*".  You're still asking for a **non-free** licence, because it doesn't respect the four freedoms / meet the OSI definition, and therefore your question is still off-topic.  That's what ArtOfCode meant about *changing it completely* - as long as you want what you say you want, your question is off-topic here, no matter what language you couch it in.  If you decide you want something else, we may be able to help.

Comment: @a_das Have a read of [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use) for a more detailed explanation of why you can't modify an open-source license like this without making it non-free/non-open.

Comment: I have modified my question one last time and then I am done. In all fairness, now that I think about it, these should have been my choice of words the first time around. Although, even if it gets re-opened, I don't think it would be the same: with the comments and downvotes, [anchoring](https://res.cloudinary.com/work911-supersite/image/upload/v1548354610/biases/anchoring.jpg) would set in, anyway! :-)

Comment: @a_das You misunderstand, I think. Let me try to clarify: unless you drop the "additional requirements" you want to add, your question will _always_ be off-topic here, because those additional requirements make what you want non-free - which we don't deal with.